# getting td element values of a particular th column using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the below html.

```
<table border="1" class="myTable">
               <tr>
                  <th class="cname">Component</th>
                  <th class="pname">Properties</th>
                  <th class="sname">lqwasb10</th>
                  <th class="sname">lqwasb11</th>
               </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">InventoryManager</td>
                     <td class="pname">maxConcurrentUpdateRetries</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">1</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">1</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
                     <td class="pname">queryASAFFabrics</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                     <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
                     <td class="pname">loggingDebug</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
                        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
                     </tr>
</table>
```

Have written the below jquery and it is not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.myTable th').each(function(){
              var server = $(this).html();
              if(server === 'lqwasb10'){
                 var b10 = $('.myTable tr td pvalue').text();
                 alert(b10);
              }
           });
       });
```

I expected the b10 could contain the below values in order.

- 1
- skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand
- false

The above code doesn't return anything. I'm a jquery newbie, it would be great if someone can help me with a solution.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('.myTable tr td propval')` isn't a valid selector. What's `propval`?

Comment: @j08691, have edited now. I'm sorry it was a typo. But the code didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably meant `$('.myTable tr td.pvalue')`. In `$('.myTable tr td pvalue')`, jQuery searches for an element named `pvalue` when it's really a class applied to a `<td>` element

Comment: yes. This I already tried but it is fetching all td values. I just want td values under lqwasb10 column. Any more suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the column you need might not always be the third column, you can use:

```
var idx;

// Find index of cell with 'lqwasb10'
$('.myTable th').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).text() === 'lqwasb10') idx = index;
})

// Loop through each cell with the same index
$('.myTable tr').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')').text())
})
```

```js
var idx;

// Find index of cell with 'lqwasb10'
$('.myTable th').each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).text() === 'lqwasb10') idx = index;
})

// Loop through each cell with the same index
$('.myTable tr').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('td:eq('+idx+')').text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th class="cname">Component</th>
    <th class="pname">Properties</th>
    <th class="sname">lqwasb10</th>
    <th class="sname">lqwasb11</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cname">InventoryManager</td>
    <td class="pname">maxConcurrentUpdateRetries</td>
    <td class="pvalue">1</td>
    <td class="pvalue">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
    <td class="pname">queryASAFFabrics</td>
    <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
    <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
    <td class="pname">loggingDebug</td>
    <td class="pvalue">false</td>
    <td class="pvalue">false</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that there's a small typo in your code example in your question. You have an extra `<tr>` after the first body row.

Comment: perfect! This is what exactly I'm looking for. Many thanks for your patience...:)

Answer (score 2):

In order to print all cells belonging to the third column you can select these cells:

```
$('.myTable tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(3)')
```

```js
$('.myTable tr:gt(0) td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
  var b10 = $(this).text();
  console.log(b10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border="1" class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="cname">Component</th>
        <th class="pname">Properties</th>
        <th class="sname">lqwasb10</th>
        <th class="sname">lqwasb11</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">InventoryManager</td>
        <td class="pname">maxConcurrentUpdateRetries</td>
        <td class="pvalue">1</td>
        <td class="pvalue">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
        <td class="pname">queryASAFFabrics</td>
        <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
        <td class="pvalue">skuType="ASAF_FABRIC" AND NOT basicColor IS NULL ORDER BY dynamicAttributes.fabricpriceband, basicColor, dynamicAttributes.fabrictype, dynamicAttributes.asafpattern, dynamicAttributes.asaffabricbrand</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cname">CatalogTools</td>
        <td class="pname">loggingDebug</td>
        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
        <td class="pvalue">false</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @gaetanoM, Could you please tell me how to iterate through th rows and get the td values. I've servername to check th server and I just have to print the td values under lqwasb10. I want to dynamically print the td values.. Thanks